# router automatically disables wifi and enables after 2-3min

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireshark

Router: Netgear DGN2200v2

Problem: THe router disables the wifi network automatically(with no human interference what so ever), thus all pc's disconnect and have no network access(as if the router was switched off, only happens for wifi connected pc's, lan pc's remain connected), then after 2-3 min the wifi comes back on again and all wifi pc's reconnect, happens 1 x every 3 days to 10-15 times a day, at random

wireshark presents 3-6 packets containing [tcp keep-alive] 53956->80 with reassembly error, new fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?) info

any have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like changing the channel and speed from N (300Mbps) to 150Mbps solved the problem